# why generated document from phpword and word template does not shows space between two words?

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, phpword

I am using phpword with microsoft word template to generate documents but when the document is processed in output word document some space doesnot appears. for example variable in document:  ${value1} ${value2} 
in output it appears without spacing:value1value2

```
$templateprocessor->setValue('value1', value('hello'));
$templateprocessor->setValue('value2', value('you'));
```

i expect output should be "hello you", but actual output is "helloyou". but in some parts of documents there is no problem.

Comment: try add space in value('hello ')

Comment: If you want to add 2 variables directly after each other, why not make them one value. You can perfectly use for example sprintf() to do this

Comment: I tried by putting space in hello also but in some case it worked but in some case it doesnot work and about the joining the two variables, i have to bold one word.

Comment: with which version did you try? I tried with the latest (0.16) and it's working fine.